# Better to way to parse a stringbuffer which is in JSON format?

Tags: java, json, jackson

My requirement is, 
I have a stringbuffer which is in JSON format, I need to parse the JSON and need to update value of few objects in JSON content and send back the updated the JSON as a stringbuffer.

Points to be taken care:
1. stringbuffer i am getting is thridparty request, which may have n number of objects in it
2. It can also have Array of object

Suggest me the best API satisfy my scenario, I have tried jacksonparser but i doesn't help..

Comment: Tried the Jackson parser? You should be able to do it fine. What have you tried?

Comment: So, parse the JSON into Lists/Maps, update as needed, serialize back to JSON.  There are easily a dozen JSON kits to choose from at json.org.  (You are correct that Jackson is probably not the best choice for this job.  Something simple like org.json is probably better.)